# Finding largest number we can make

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

The problem is from [yesterday's contest from Codeforces](https://codeforces.com/contest/1157/problem/B).

I have observed that, from the left side (i.e. MSB), for every digit, if we replace the given number with the output of `f` when after passing the digit - we get a bigger number we will get the desired output. I'm a beginner in programming and have written code with Python 3, which is showing TLE after submission (though it is correct and gives correct output for the sample test cases). I think a better algorithm is needed.

Variables `st` (start index), `flag`, `cntr` (length of **contiguous subsegment** ) are taken for the condition the part where we will replace the digits needs to be **contiguous subsegment**:

```
n = int(input())
s = input()
f = list(map(int,input().split()))
result = []
st = -1
flag = 1 
cntr = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    x=f[int(s[i])-1]
    if(x>int(s[i])):
        result.append(str(x)) 
        if(flag==1):
            st = i 
            flag = 0
        if(flag==0):
            cntr+=1 
    else:
        result.append(s[i])
        if(st!=-1 and (i-st-1)!=cntr):
            break
for j in range(i+1,len(s)):
    result.append(s[j])
#print(result)
r = int(''.join(result))
print(r)
```

Can anyone make any improvement in my code? I know there is a tutorial on that website, but I want to learn how to develop code which I have written already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speed issue can be fixed by using PyPy 3  as it is faster (at least in most codeforces type problems, I don't know in general)

However this will result in a WA verdict. To fix this just modify the break condition as follows and it will work:

```
if(st!=-1 and x!=int(s[i])):
```

This is because the current version can sometimes break out of the loop prematurely when \$x == int(s[i])\$ because it may be better to make the segment longer.

Finally, I consider you are using too many flag variables, only one is required. Here is how I would change the code:

```
n = int(input())
s = input()
f = list(map(int,input().split()))
result = []
flag = 1 
for i in range(len(s)):
    x=f[int(s[i])-1]
    if(x>int(s[i])):
        result.append(str(x)) 
        if(flag==1):
            flag = 0
    else:
        result.append(s[i])
        if(flag!=1 and x!=int(s[i])):
            break
for j in range(i+1,len(s)):
    result.append(s[j])
#print(result)
r = int(''.join(result))
print(r)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. Not getting why we need to break the loop when `x!=int(s[i])` given `flag!=1`. In every iteration, `x` will be loaded with `f[int(s[i])-1]`. I used the break statement to check if after starting the replacement we no more have greater number as output.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what the reasoning behind (i-st-1)!=cntr is. But you just need to break as soon as there is a value such that x<int(s[i]) because then it becomes clear that you shouldn't make the segment that you are applying f to any longer.

Comment: Ok, so we can use `x<int(s[i])`. If I use `x!=int(s[i])` there, as, every time `x` is getting updated by `f[int(s[i])-1]`, the loop will break after just replacing one digit, as the `flag=0` at that time already. About my program, I am storing the index of the digit, where first replacement occurs, in `st` variable. Increasing the var. `cntr` everytime when replacement occurs. But when for first time(after replacement has started for `st` th digit) when we get `x<int(s[i])` the `cntr` will not be updated and the value of `(i-st-1)` and `cntr` will be not same.

Comment: well yeah but the cntr variable isn' very usefull, the only part where you use cntr is in the (i-st-1)!=cntr part. But I dont understand that part. Also, notice that the flag variable isnt used , you can just use the st variable.

Comment: Thank you. I wish your channel would be in English :)

Comment: There's a lot of better channels in english